# Difference between static variable and global variable in C++ in terms of Memory Management?

Tags: c++, static-methods

Difference between static variable and global variable in C++ in terms of Memory Management?

Difference between static method and global method in C++?

i know the concepts, but still for clear understanding ,explain in simple words

Comment: Difference in terms of what? Accessability? Memory management? Declaration?

Comment: Please update your question with code to show what you mean by those words. 'Global method' doesn't mean anything to me, 'static variable' could mean several things.

Comment: Both are soooo easily googlable, that I will not dignify this with an answer...

Comment: There are plenty of QA's on Stackoverflow that cover these topics.

Comment: Difference between smart and lazy question? [explained here](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro)

Comment: i asked in terms of Memory Management ..

Comment: No difference between a global variable and any kind of static variable in terms of memory management. I'm guessing you really mean object lifetime, Global variables are constructed some time before the program starts. Static variables in function scope are constructed some time before they are used.

Comment: Now, c'mon people, don't make Pixel loose all of his hard earned rep just because he asked one question. Who throws the first stone?

Comment: @Pixel It's impossible to know *your* difference between "knowing the concepts" and "clearly understanding".  Can you explain what you know and what you're unsure of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in terms of memory management. Static variables and global variables both have "static storage duration", which means they are destroyed when the program exits.